# How to run a python script automatically using macbook automator when a certain file is changed?

Tags: python, macos, automator

I have created a python script called **recipe_jsonifier.py** which opens and uses data from **links.txt** file whenever it is executed. Currently everytime I update the text file, I have to manually run the python script to uses data from the text file. I need to make it so the python script runs automatically whenever I make a change to the text file. I have no experience in using the Macbook Automator.

1. Are there other ways I can make the python script run automatically without using the Macbook automator?
2. If not, What steps do I need to take in order to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: I have used `fswatch` which you can install with **homebrew** and it works well. There appears to be a Python version which I have not tried... https://pypi.org/project/fswatch/

Comment: Ok I have installed fswatch. But I have no idea about how to use it. I read the documentation, but there was no mention on how to use it to run a script when a file is changed. How do I use it? Also is there any way I can make it run automatically when the macbook is started?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fswatch` for this. Install it with **homebrew**:

```
brew install fswatch
```

Then if you want to monitor a file in your HOME directory called `monitored.txt` make the following script and save it as `$HOME/monitor.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
fswatch -x -0 $HOME/monitored.txt | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} say "I saw that"
```

Then make it executable with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/monitor.sh
```

and run it to test with:

```
$HOME/monitor.sh
```

Now start a new Terminal and run:

```
touch $HOME/monitored.txt
touch $HOME/monitored.txt
rm $HOME/monitored.txt
```

and each command will result in the words *"I saw that"* being spoken.

---

Once you get that working, you will need to read up on `launchctl`. Basically, if you want it to monitor a file as soon as the system starts up, you will need to make a *"LaunchDaemon"*. That will be a file called something like:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.YOURNAME.monitor.plist
```

And in that file, you will need something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.YOURNAME.monitor</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/YOURNAME/monitor.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/YOURNAME</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>YOURNAME</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.YOURNAME.monitor.stdout</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.YOURNAME.monitor.stderr</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then read up on `launchctl load` and `launchctl start` and test it all.